# Purple artifacts in RDP session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, hyper-v, visual-artifacts

I'm having an intermittent issue where I get purple artefacting in my RDP session.

[image: Artifacting]

The RDP is to a local Hyper-V machine which is configured to use RemoteFX. I have a nVidia GTX 970 with the latest drivers (375.70)

This is my RDP configuration

> screen mode id:i:2
>   use multimon:i:1
>   desktopwidth:i:1920
>   desktopheight:i:1200
>   session bpp:i:32
>   winposstr:s:0,1,608,165,1408,765
>   compression:i:0
>   keyboardhook:i:2
>   audiocapturemode:i:0
>   videoplaybackmode:i:1
>   connection type:i:6
>   networkautodetect:i:0
>   bandwidthautodetect:i:1
>   displayconnectionbar:i:1
>   enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
>   disable wallpaper:i:0
>   allow font smoothing:i:1
>   allow desktop composition:i:1
>   disable full window drag:i:0
>   disable menu anims:i:0
>   disable themes:i:0
>   disable cursor setting:i:0
>   bitmapcachepersistenable:i:0
>   full address:s:win10-dev-vm
>   audiomode:i:0
>   redirectprinters:i:0
>   redirectcomports:i:0
>   redirectsmartcards:i:1
>   redirectclipboard:i:1
>   redirectposdevices:i:0
>   drivestoredirect:s:R:\;
>   autoreconnection enabled:i:1
>   authentication level:i:2
>   prompt for credentials:i:0
>   negotiate security layer:i:1
>   remoteapplicationmode:i:0
>   alternate shell:s:
>   shell working directory:s:
>   gatewayhostname:s:
>   gatewayusagemethod:i:4
>   gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
>   gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
>   promptcredentialonce:i:0
>   use redirection server name:i:0
>   rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
>   kdcproxyname:s:
>   gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
>   devicestoredirect:s:*

If I close the RDP sessions and re-open it, the artefacts goes away for a while but then comes back.

Has anyone seen this before or got any thoughts about how to resolve it.

Comment: What OS are both client and server?

Comment: Both are Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**On the client machine:**

Can you please open `gpedit.msc` and then navigate to `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Connection Client` and then on the right hand side there should be a setting `Do not allow hardware accelerated decoding` - please double click and enable that setting, apply and restart the remote desktop client.

**Background** - this is an active bug already captured via the feedback tool and being worked on for the next release of Windows 10 (Creator's Update).

Answer (score 5):

If disabling "hardware accelerated decoding" fails in solving this problem on Win10 try with deleting cached files at:

**C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache**

on **client machine**.

Comment: A Simpler access to that path is: `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache`

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 2):

This looks hardware decoding problem. Have you tried disabling hardware accelerated decoding on the RDP client machine? The Group Policy setting is available under the "Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Connection Client".

Answer (score 0):

The group policy setting sets the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\Client]
"EnableHardwareMode"=dword:00000000
```